# Need to show ALL authors in a table

Tags: sql

I need to have all Authors on the table, even if they didn't make a book.  Right now, it's all Authors that made a book.

Schema:

Authors: Au_ID (1, 2, 3, etc...), Author (Name of the author...)

Publisher: PubID (1, 2, 3, etc...), Company Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Telephone

Title: Title (Title of the book), Year (####), ISBN(ex. 0-0038307-6-4 ), PubID (1, 2, 3, etc), Subject

Wrote: ISBN, Au_ID

```
SELECT Authors.Author, Title.Title
FROM Authors, Title, Publisher, Wrote
WHERE Authors.Au_ID = Wrote.Au_ID AND Title.ISBN = Wrote.ISBN AND Publisher.PubID = Title.PubID
GROUP BY Author, Title;
```

What do I do in order to include all the authors, even without a book?

Comment: select authors.author from authors ?

Comment: Select Authors.author FROM Author will give me all of the Authors from the Authors table. I could just do Select Author... but I like to be extra careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OUTER JOIN`. Authors without books will have `NULL` in `Title.Title`.

```
SELECT Authors.Author, Title.Title
FROM Authors LEFT JOIN Wrote ON  Authors.Au_ID = Wrote.Au_ID 
    LEFT JOIN Title ON Title.ISBN = Wrote.ISBN
GROUP BY Author, Title;
```

Comment: @BIoodFox, can you provide the full query syntax and error message? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca7b1/2 seems to work, but I can't get your database schema.

Comment: Syntax error(Missing operator) in query expression 'Authors.Au_ID = Wrote.Au_ID LEFT JOIN Title ON Title.ISBN = Wrote.ISBN LEFT JOIN Publisher ON Publisher.PubID = Title.PubID '.

Comment: @BIoodFox it doesn't seem to need Publisher here. Updated the query. Please provide full query and error message if the problem persists.

Comment: @BIoodFox take a look at sqlfiddle with your schema, it works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67311/2/0

Comment: Same error message. I'm using Microsoft Access for this SQL query.  I have written exactly what you have up there, since I haven't understood joins fully, yet.

Comment: @BIoodFox perhaps some MS Access-related problems. Can you give the **full** error message?

Comment: Syntax error(Missing operator) in query expression 'Authors.Au_ID = Wrote.Au_ID LEFT JOIN Title ON Title.ISBN = Wrote.ISB'.

Comment: I'm going to stick to this answer, and just assume it's Microsoft Access breaking everything.  Thanks!